# Cannot load the data from local json file using fetch with Parcel live server

Tags: javascript, fetch, parceljs

I have a simple plain javascript project. When trying to load the content of a JSON file from a javascript I get the following error. Nothing fancy, all files are in the same folder but I don't understand why it's not working.

```js
index.js
function loadFiles() {
  fetch("test.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => console.log(json));
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="loadFiles()">
  Hello
</body>
</html>
```

test.json

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age":25,
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Sample Javascript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "source": "index.html",
  "browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 2 versions, not dead",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel",
    "build": "parcel build"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.19.0",
    "parcel": "^2.8.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.8.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
  }
}
```

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON[image: error message]

I tried without the parcel live server but using the visual studio live server and it works without any problem.

Comment: Can you share your JSON data

Comment: @BennisonJ  it's a sample JSON file. I have updated the issue

Comment: Take a look at your network tab in your devtools. Is that request giving you a 404?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting html, not json in the fetch response.
Parcel supports [json imports](https://parceljs.org/languages/json/)

Add type `module` to your script  `<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>` and you can just import json like this:

```
import data from './test.json';
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Yes, currently I'm doing this but I wanted to know why 'Fetch' was not working with Parcel. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bahmutov/parcel-json-server

Answer (score 0):

The Parcel dev server [isn't designed to serve static files](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/3407).

You are expected to host them on another webserver.

If you need them to be on the same origin then you can [configure Parcel to act as a proxy](https://parceljs.org/features/development/#api-proxy).